# How to pass input from command line to junit maven test program

Tags: maven, junit, junit4

I wrote a junit test to add two numbers. I need to pass this numbers from command line. I am running this junit test from maven tool as

```
mvn -Dtest=AddNumbers
```

My test program looks like this

```
int num1 = 1;
int num2 = 2;

@Test
public void addNos() {
  System.out.println((num1 + num2));
}
```

How to pass these numbers from command line?

Comment: can we please have an answer marked here

Answer (score 46):

Passing the numbers as system properties like suggested by @artbristol is a good idea, but I found that it is not always guaranteed that these properties will be propagated to the test.

To be sure to pass the system properties to the test use the [maven surefire plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/) [argLine](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#argLine) parameter, like

```
mvn -Dtest=AddNumbers -DargLine="-Dnum1=1 -Dnum2=2"
```

Answer (score 20):

To pass input from command line to junit maven test program you follow these steps. For example if you need to pass parameter **fileName** into unit test executed by Maven, then follow the steps:

1. In the JUnit code - parameter will be passed via System properties:

   ```
   @BeforeClass
   public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
       String fileName = System.getProperty("fileName");
       log.info("Reading config file : " + fileName);
   }
   ```
2. In pom.xml - specify param name in surefire plugin configuration, and use {fileName} notation to force maven to get actual value from System properties

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
           <!-- since 2.5 -->
           <systemPropertyVariables>
              <fileName>${fileName}</fileName>
           </systemPropertyVariables>
           <!-- deprecated -->
           <systemProperties>
               <property>
                   <name>fileName</name>
                   <value>${fileName}</value>
               </property>
           </systemProperties>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```
3. In the command line pass fileName parameter to JVM system properties:

   ```
   mvn clean test -DfileName=my_file_name.txt
   ```

Answer (score 16):

You can pass them on the command line like this

`mvn -Dtest=AddNumbers -Dnum1=100`

then access them in your test with

`int num1=Integer.valueOf(System.getProperty("num1"));`

Comment: if we need to pass string parameter, how to do it?